# between what two disjoint sections we can do a Union in order to get this group of solutions?

Tags: calculus

between what two disjoint sections we can do a Union in order to get this group of solutions?

$0<|x+6|\leq{0.4}$

in other words, in what values should I fill the blankets:

(____),(____) $\cup$ (____ ,___ )

in order to get two ranges which their Union of the group of solutions above.  $0<|x+6|\leq{0.4}$

and what kind of brackets should I use? the ones that I wrote are not accurate !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* Note that $0<|x+6|\le 0.4$ means that $0<x+6\le 0.4$ or $0<-(x+6)\le 0.4$

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest approach is to solve the equations independantly and then take the intersection of the solutions:

$0<|x+6|\iff 0<x+6< 0\iff x+6\neq0 \iff x\neq-6 $

$|x+6|\leq0.4 \iff -0.4\leq x+6\leq0.4 \iff -6.4\leq x\leq -5.6 \iff x\in [-6.4,-5.6]$

So we ant the $x's$ that are in $[-6.4,-5.6]$ that are not $-6$, so the final answer is:

$x\in[-6.4,-6)\cup(-6,-5.6]$